# Tensorflow object detection api with weird detection result

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I have trained tensorflow object detection api on my own dataset with 1 class using rfcn_resnet101 model. Firstly I used the raccoon dataset and trained for 264600 times and the detection result is weird, it can detect the object, but there are some other little boxes around the right box.

[image: Raccoon example]

Then I use another dataset containing one class,and there are 80000 images in the dataset, I met the familiar phenomenon. I am very confused.

[image]

Have anyone ever met the same situation? What can I do to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same behavior on the PASCAL VOC Dataset. I haven't fixed it, because I just implemented a model for kind of a proof-of-concept system. My guess is, that the model predicts the proposal regions and accepts them, if there is an IoU greater or equal to an defined threshold. So setting the `nms_iou_threshold` might solve the problem.

This Adoption also seems to fit your examples. All of the predicted bounding boxes seem to have an IoU with the groundtruth box.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to change the first_stage_nms_iou_threshold to a higher value, but the phenomenon is still here. what's more, the predicted bounding boxes sometimes is outside the groundtruth  box. I really don't why this happen.

Comment: Then try to increse `the iou_threshold` in the `second_stage_post_processing` block

Comment: Thank you again. I tried to increase the iou_threshold but the problem still can't be solved. I want to try other models. I want to know whether you solve the problem or not.